# Having clause not working with join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to find out average sale price in certain period.

Data set(Short):

```
*products*
productID name 
       1 Beef Burger   
       2 Crispy Chicken Burger

*sale_products*
productID sale_price quantity created       
        1       500   4       2016-01-30 16:19:01
        2       600   5       2016-01-30 17:52:33
        1       450   3       2016-01-30 17:58:33
        2       570   5       2016-02-01 11:57:01
```

My query is:

```
select products.name, sum(sale_products.sale_price * sale_products.quantity) / sum(sale_products.quantity) as Avarage from sale_products inner join products on sale_products.productID = products.productID and sale_products.created BETWEEN "2016-01-30 16:19:01" and "2016-02-01 11:57:01" group by sale_products.productID
```

It gives the exact result that I want.

The Result:

[image]

But Previously I tried that query:

```
select products.name, sum(sale_products.sale_price * sale_products.quantity) / sum(sale_products.quantity) as Avarage from sale_products inner join products on sale_products.productID = products.productID group by sale_products.productID having sale_products.created BETWEEN "2016-01-30 16:19:01" and "2016-02-01 11:57:01"
```

It gave error - Unknown column 'sale_products.created' in 'having clause' . Why having clause don't work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause `HAVING` clause is used to specify condition on group or an aggregate functions. It operates on the column(s) specified on the `GROUP BY` clause. In your case `sale_products.created` is not a grouping column and so you get the said error. To examine, put that column in your `GROUP BY` clause like `group by sale_products.productID, sale_products.created` and it will work though will give a undesired result. You should rather move that condition to `WHERE` like

```
where sale_products.created BETWEEN "2016-01-30 16:19:01" and "2016-02-01 11:57:01"
```

To test, check this demo fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94de5/3

Comment: In last query I used `HAVING` for aggregate function on `sum()`. Then what was the wrong.

Comment: Then, if I use any grouping column with `HAVING` clause then it will be work?

Comment: Yeah, that's what is meant.